# Discord.js V13 send .sqlite file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
const { owner } = require('../config/config.json')
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const moment = require('moment')
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD-MM-SS')

module.exports = {
    name: "data",

    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.member.id === owner) {
            const promise = fs.promises.readFile(path.join('./data.sqlite')); 

            Promise.resolve(promise).then(function (buffer) {
                console.log(promise)
                console.log(buffer)
                interaction.member.send({
                    content: `**${today} database**\n⁣`, files: [
                        { attachment: buffer }
                    ]
                }).catch(err => console.log(err) && interaction.member.send(`err!\n\n**${err}**`));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to send the data.sqlite file to my DM.
When I use the above code, transferring the picture file works very well, but when I transfer the .sqlite file it sends the wrong file. How do I send a json.sqlite file to my DM?

Comment: Please clarify your goal. It's hard to understand what you want. What is the "picture file" and what do you mean by "transferring" it?

Comment: Sending the file is what I want.

Comment: Sending which file exactly?

Comment: I want to transfer a file called data.sqlite.

But it seems that the file was forcibly converted to jpg.

Comment: What does the jpg look like?